# Sphinx: Bibtex bibliography with EPUB generator

Tags: python-sphinx, bibtex

I'm trying to utilize Sphinx to build three fold output - HTML, Latex, and EPUB. The bibliography is standard bibtex. With HTML and Latex it works perfectly well. However, EPUB generator:

```
sphinx-build -b epub -D extensions=sphinx.ext.imgmath -D imgmath_embed=True . epub/
```

produces the following errors:

```
WARNING: unknown directive or role name: cite:t
3-poplavni.rst:170: ERROR: Unknown interpreted text role "cite:t".
literatura.rst:7: ERROR: Unknown directive type "bibliography".

.. bibliography::
```

Any advice?

EPUB generator should work well with Bibtex as Latex and HTML generators do.

Comment: I presume that you have `sphinxcontrib.bibtex` in the value of `extensions` in conf.py. With `-D extensions=sphinx.ext.imgmath` on the command line, you override that configuration value. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-D.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! As you suggested:

```
sphinx-build -b epub -D extensions=sphinx.ext.imgmath,sphinxcontrib.bibtex -D imgmath_embed=True . epub/
```

works like a charm.